# Update time series on the basis of columns in data frame

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame df as

```
Name    DoApply
T1      No
T2      Yes
T3      No
```

and time series object z as

```
                T1      T2      T3
2013-01-18      20      15      21
2013-01-20      30      18      17
2013-01-21      10      21      24
2013-01-22      15      17      15
2013-01-23      18      16      18
```

I want output as on basis of yes or no

```
                T1      T2      T3
2013-01-18      20      0       21
2013-01-20      30      0       17
2013-01-21      10      0       24
2013-01-22      15      0       15
2013-01-23      18      0       18
```

I am trying something like this, but could not do it

```
coredata(z)[match something from df] <- 0
```

Comment: Is it xts object or zoo object?

Comment: its zoo. I created it using read.zoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
z[,df$DoApply[match(colnames(z), df$Name)]=='Yes'] <- 0
```

Or

```
 z[,with(df, Name[DoApply=='Yes'])] <- 0
```